# Laravel4.2の認証よりもSentryの方が良いのでしょうか？

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel を使ってみようと思っています。
チュートリアルと称したページを見ると、ビルトインの認証でなく
Sentry を導入している人が多いです。
Sentry を使用するメリットを教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1):

#### Pros

機能以外の面で言えば、Sentry 2はLaravel 4とは基本的に独立していて、
CodeIgniterやFuelPHPのインテグレーションが存在する。
つまり、他フレームワークでも同じように使える、あるいは他フレームワークからの移行がしやすい。

#### Cons

独立してるがゆえに標準とは違う方法になる。標準のやり方でいくなら[Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide)のほうが良い。
また、現行のLaravel 5に対応していないため、将来性が不安。

Comment: Confide + Entrust でロール管理ができるのですね。Laravel 5 は 4系と結構違いがあるようなので、今回は割り切って 4.2 で考えています。